# why does CAT command is not working in android device?

Tags: android, command, cat

I am working in android application. I want to copy data from 1 file to other file.I have executed below command for it, but not able to copy data from file1 -> file 2.

```
     // Executes the command.
        String CAT_COMMAND = "cat /sdcard/file1 > /sdcard/file2";
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CAT_COMMAND);
```

I have used ADB SHELL command at DOS , executed CAT command which works fine.
 But code execution is not working into the real devices.

please help me out why does it is not copying data from file1->file2.??

provide resolution for writing/copying data using CAT command.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the error msg ? Is it the permission related error ? Is the device rooted ?

Comment: I have checked at rooted and non rooted device, but it is not giving any types of error or permission related exception. It is just executing the code , but result is nothing. Let me know if you have any other alternative to copy data file using CAT command. I have used ADB SHELL command at DOS , executed CAT command which works fine.

Comment: try using `cat "/sdcard/file1" > "/sdcard/file2"`

Comment: Try adding this before you call exec.                              Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

Comment: @idiottiger not working that as well.. :(

Comment: @m4n07 In my opinion SU is required only to get Super User Access. My primary target is to get this working in non-rooted device.

Answer (score 0):

can you try with the complete path /mnt/sdcard .(or) Try to get the right path by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Comment: I have used Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() and /mnt/sdcard also , but it is not working ....